# Architecture Kubernetes + microservices

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, microservices, kops, kubernetes-pod

I need to design a website solution with multiple spa pages.
What I thought as a high-level design is as below:-

There will be one machine for each spa page which will just render the UI, do SSR and take request from the browser.
For example, www.abc.com/foo will be routed to this machine. I'm thinking of to put the application UI code in kubernetes pod and host that on the machine/node. Also using KOPS I will manage the autoscaling of nodes and pods.

Now, this application in the pod will call other pods for data to be shown on the web page. For example, www.abc.com/API/foo will be called from pod1. I'm thinking to make this another pod which will live on the same node as the web page pod node.

So now I have 2 pods living on a single node which will autoscale as per traffic.
Similarly, for each page I have on my website I will have a node with 2 pods each.

My questions now are below:-

1. Is there any best practice or other design solution for above?
2. How will I achieve path based routing like www.abc.com/foo should call my web page pod?
3. How can I expose the pod to external world i.e. internet without using a load balancer?
4. Should I have different repos for each pod?

Comment: Will `Ingress` work for your needs? Usage: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#simple-fanout, Deploying: https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/tree/master/addons/ingress-nginx

Comment: I'm bit confused about what ingress does and also is it in production stage?

Comment: It sounds too over complicated for just serving static content. Are you sure that having just one nginx (even without Kubernetes but properly configured) wouldn't be enough?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any best practice or other design solution for above?

You can use [`PodAffinity`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/) to co-locate your pods.

> How will I achieve path based routing like www.abc.com/foo should call
>   my web page pod?

You can use a Kubernetes [`Ingress`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/). Since this is a layer 7 facility you will able to do multiple host paths, keep in mind that this is generally exposed to the outside using a LoadBalancer type of service.

> How can I expose the pod to external world i.e. internet without using
>   a load balancer?

You can use a [`NodePort`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#nodeport) type of `Service`. Note that you generally use either an Ingress or a NodePort service, the downside for this approach is that you won't be able to do paths and that will have to be handled in your application.

> Should I have different repos for each pod?

git repos? sure, you will have to have different container images for each application.

Comment: Ingress is in beta and supports only http.i need https support.

Comment: It supports https too.